# React not going to JavaScript function that is manually built

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario in which I need to modify code from a promise to wrap a link around it.

I came up with this.

```
const modifiedValue = <a onClick={this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;
```

It is not working:

```
//function
jsfunction = (test) => {
   console.log('test', test)
}
```

I tried to bind in the constructor too:

```
this.jsfunction = this.jsfunction.bind(this);
```

Seems if I remove the `onClick` then it is worse,  also removing the href, JavaScript: is that needed ?

Comment: This doesn't really look like React at all. Can you post a full code file here so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: It certainly does look like React.   Notice the bind(this)  - that is in the constructor.  The javascript function is just a simple arrow function.   The main const is from a promise that is returned before i do a setState   ,  most of React is javascript

Comment: The onClick handler should be the function to execute when clicked. Right now, you're setting the onClick whatever jsfunction resolves to. To make it work, change the onClick to: `e => this.jsfunction(item.value)`

Comment: @JacobPenney   I get a syntax issue   `onClick= e =>`

Comment: `const modifiedValue = <a onClick={e=>this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;`

Comment: @JacobPenney    Nice.  thank you  - feel free to write up that as an answer   thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick handler should be the function to execute when clicked. Right now, you're setting the onClick whatever jsfunction resolves to. To make it work, change the onClick to: e => this.jsfunction(item.value)

Use:

```
const modifiedValue = <a onClick={e=>this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;
```